# How can I view the Squid access log file in PHP?

Tags: php, logging, webserver, echo, squid

I'm trying to access the content of the Squid access log file to show it on a simple webpage with PHP, but whatever I do, the page turns out white. Please note, this is a test environment, so every 777 you see, I'm not intending to use that in a live server.

I also get that you can't directly view or edit the access.log file in PHP due to limitations or security reasons by the way. Here's what I've done so far:

- Changed the permission of the access.log file to 777
- Changed the ownership of the access.log file to apache
- Changed every permission in the /var/www/html folder to 777
- Changed the ownership to apache
- Changed the permission on the Squid log file to 777
- I copied the access.log file to /var/www/html/squid-log folder
- I renamed the access.log file in the /var/www/html/squid-log folder to test.txt

The PHP code I use is simple:

```
<?php
$logging =file_get_contents("test.txt");
echo $logging;
?>
```

But the page turns out empty every time. If I click on the text.txt file on the sites index, it gives me a **"Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /test.txt" on this server"**
What am I doing wrong here? I already searched for it and also on this forum, but I couldn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Did you check your server's error log for any error showing up? Is your PHP code in the same folder?

Comment: All I see is that the permission is denied to the file in the error_log of httpd. And yeah, my PHP code is in the same folder. Here's the ls output: rwxrwxrwx. 1 apache apache     10 Apr 17 09:34 test.txt

Comment: That `ls` output says there's a `test.txt` file in that folder - that's it. Is your PHP script in `/var/www/html` or in `/var/www/html/squid-log`?

Comment: My php file is in /var/www/html/squid-log and so is the test.txt

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. SELinux was the cause. I set it up to accept connections from ssh, but after I disabled it, I was able to view the content on my webpage. :)

I would want to answer my own question, but for some reason I need to wait for 2 days to do that.